# Android has stopped working after clicking the send button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, textview

I'm following this tutorials:

> 1. http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-1-3-how-to-change-a-color-of-text-and-background-in-textview/
> 2. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

I'm modifying the DisplayMessageActivity to change the color of the output text and change the background using xml.

I'm having problems with the code, when I try to run this, my android application closes. The app is to display the text that was written from the previous view and display it using the another view when clicking the Send button.

DisplayMessageAcitivity:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // Get the message from the intent
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.DisplayActivityMessageTextView);
 // Create the text view
 textView.setText(message);
 // Set the text view as the activity layout
 setContentView(textView);
}
```

I have 2 XML file: activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml I have included the textView in the fragment_main.xml.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/DisplayActivityMessageTextView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="@color/opaque_red" />
```

Strings.xml:

`<color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>`

Logcat:

```
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 25966
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966):
...
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 10:22:43.919: E/AndroidRuntime(25966):
...
```

Comment: First change  `findViewById R.id.DisplayActivityMessageTextView)` to  `findViewById(R.id.DisplayActivityMessageTextView)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `setContentView(textView);` before `findViewById`

i.e. rewrite your code as

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // Set the text view as the activity layout
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // Get the message from the intent
   }
```

and change

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
```

to

```
  Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
```

and use

```
  Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
     String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
     TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById R.id.DisplayActivityMessageTextView);
     // Create the text view
     textView.setText(message);
```

in `onCreateView` of your `mainFragment` because `DisplayActivityMessageTextView` is part of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just an educated guess. This declaration...

```
<color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
```

Must be placed inside the `colors.xml` resource file instead of the `strings.xml` resource file

Or, if you don't want to create a new file. At least change this in your `TextView`...

```
android:textColor="@color/opaque_red"
```

to...

```
android:textColor="@string/opaque_red"
```

Comment: I was able to use it using this code in Java: textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.opaque_red)); is there a difference between placing it on a color.xml rather than the strings.xml? Sorry I'm new to Android.

Comment: No, I don't think so. But you do have to reference the correct resource in your layout `@string/name`, `@color/name`, `@drawable/name`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, put

```
setContentView(textView);
```

before

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById R.id.DisplayActivityMessageTextView);
```

Comment: That won't even compile because the instance textView is created after it is passed to setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

you Should use Bundle to get extra

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

     String message = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `findViewById()` only works with an *inflated* (that means all views in the layout are created as objects from the layout xml) layout. When you call `setContentView(R.layout.asdf)` the layout is automatically beeing inflated. Since you don't inflate the layout that contains your `DisplayActivityMessageTextView`, the view can't b found and `textVeiw` is null, wich causes a NullPointerException. 
I suggest instead of `findViewById` you just create a new TextView:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

and for setting the textColor:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.opaque_red));
```

An other problem migth be that your opaque_red is definded in Srtings.xml. The file should be called Colors.xml